# How to interpret Universal Quantifier in Alternating Turing Machines?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, co-np

I am trying to read about Alternating Turing Machines (ATM) that have both existential and universal quantifiers for all their *internal* states. Given that these models are conceptual, I tend to imagine that there is some form of reflection in terms of an advantage provided to the deterministic Turing Machine to provide it the same power as an ATM. What advantage does this correspond for the universal quantifier?

For example, I understand that a **certificate** is provided to a deterministic Turing Machine to make it as powerful as a non-deterministic Turing Machine with an existential quantifier, but I fail to understand the correspondence for the universal quantifier.

It has been indicated that alternations of both quantifiers form some form of a trade-off between space and time. I understand that providing the certificate saves you time from searching all the examples, thus saving you some time at the cost of space occupied by the certificate. So naturally, the universal quantifier should provide you with the opposite. How does using a universal quantifier save you space at the cost of time? Won't checking for all certificates take both space *and* time?

Comment: Should I move it to cstheory stackexchange perhaps? can this be migrated by moderators?

Comment: It's not a reasearch-level question, so it's not suited to cstheory and would be closed there. You can think an universal quantifier as a way to "prove" (compute) non existence: $\lnot \exists x.  \varphi(x) \equiv \forall x. \lnot \varphi(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, alternating Turing machines are nondeterministic, but have both existential and universal states. In an existential state one of the possible computations should accept, in a universal state all possible continuations should accept. In this way an ordinary nondeterministic TM corresponds to an alternating TM with only existential states.

In my intuition a certificate is a way to resolve nondeterminism by specifying the correct continuation of the computation in the certificate.

Universal quantification enables one to reuse both space and time. At a universal state the computation tree splits. As basically time is measured as the depth of the computation tree, practically both continuing computations are run in parallel.

One of the important results in complexity theory is the result of Savitch that nondeterministic space is equivalent to deterministic space. The intuitive reason is that space can be reused. Time ticks on, but we can erase the tape and test another computation in the same space. If there are many computations to check, we have to reserve space for the bookkeeping of computations too. Thus Savitch' result is
$NSPACE( s(n) ) \subseteq SPACE( s^2(n) )$. Then $NPSPACE = PSPACE$, nondeterministic polynomial space equals deterministic polynomial space.

The same technique can be used with alternation, to move from parallel in space to parallel in time. Chandra and Stockmeyer show that
$NSPACE( s(n) ) \subseteq ATIME( s^2(n) )$. Then $NSPACE = AP$ or (non)deterministic polynomials space equals alternating polynomial time.